# What is the ticker symbol of the mini Google stock?

Tags: stocks

I was told there is a "mini" version of the Google stock, but I cannot find the ticker symbol for it.

What is the ticker symbol of the mini Google?

Answer (score 1):

Google will be issuing Class C shares (under the ticker symbol GOOCV) to current GOOG holders in the beginning of April.  The Class C shares and Class A shares will then change symbols, with the Class C shares trading under GOOG.  This was announced on January 30th.

Details are in this [benzinga](http://www.benzinga.com/news/14/02/4294511/nasdaq-offers-timeline-for-distribution-of-googles-class-c-shares) article:

> Projected Trading Timeline
>
> March 27 - April 2
>
> Record Date - Payment Date
>
> Class C shares commence trading on March 27 as GOOCV on a when issued basis Class A shares continue to trade as GOOG, with entitlement to Class C shares Class A shares will also trade on an ex-distribution basis, without entitlement to the Class C shares, as GOOAV
>
> April 3
>
> EX Date
>
> The ticker for the Class A shares will change from GOOG to GOOGL The ticker for the Class C shares will change from GOOCV to GOOG and commence regular way trading The ticker for the Class A shares that traded on an ex-distribution basis - GOOAV - will be suspended